# increment variable using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I feel like this is a pretty basic thing, but I cant seem to find the solution.  Im trying to increment a value after the loading of an IFRAME.

the code looks like this:

```
var x=0;
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#iframe-2').load(function() {
            var x=x+1;        
        });
        $('#iframe-3').load(function() {
            var x=x+1;    
        });
        $('#iframe-4').load(function() {
            var x=x+1;        
        });
        $('#iframe-5').load(function() {
            var x=x+1;        
        });
    });
```

What I want to do is give a number of loaded iframes that updates when an iframe completes its loading.  The output code is like this currently:

```
<script language="javascript">
document.write(x + " Results");
</script>
```

thanks a ton in advance for any help!

Comment: You are creating a local copy of `x` each time you use a `var`. Remove `var` inside `load` function. Also, place `var x = 0` inside `document.ready`

Comment: @user791187 Check my answer, i give you a demo.

Comment: See [xdazz's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/762073/xdazz) updated answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338499/increment-variable-using-jquery/11338529#11338529), I think this is it, accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally came up with a very simple solution:

```
var x=0;

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#iframe-2').load(function() {
            $("#t2").css("display","inline");
            x++;
            document.getElementById("tabs-1").innerHTML=x + " Results";
        });

        $('#iframe-3').load(function() {
            $("#t3").css("display","inline");
            x++;
            document.getElementById("tabs-1").innerHTML=x + " Results";
        });

        $('#iframe-4').load(function() {
            $("#t4").css("display","inline");
            x++;
            document.getElementById("tabs-1").innerHTML=x + " Results";
        });
        $('#iframe-5').load(function() {
            $("#t5").css("display","inline");
            x++;
            document.getElementById("tabs-1").innerHTML=x + " Results";
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 17):

You should change

```
var x = x+1;
```

to

```
x = x+1
```

Because the `var` keyword is creating a new variable every time in your every `load` so global variable `x` is not getting updated/incremented.

Comment: Ok, I removed the semicolon from each, but Im still getting "0 results" when the iframes load.  As a heads-up, Im really new to both javascript & jquery, so if its possible to dumb it down a little, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Not semicolons, remove the keyword `var`

Comment: got it! thank you.  Im still getting the same result..."0 results"

Comment: Put `document.write(x + " Results");` after the last `load` of iframr.

Comment: When I did this, it somehow broke the code...now nothing on the page loads except the "0 results" which appears at the top

Answer (score 7):

You declare local variable in the load callback function, so it will not increase the global `x`, you could declare `var x` inside of dom ready callback function, and use it in load callback function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = 0;
    $('#iframe-2').load(function() {
        x++;        
    });
    $('#iframe-3').load(function() {
        x++;
    });
    $('#iframe-4').load(function() {
        x++;  
    });
    $('#iframe-5').load(function() {
        x++;  
    });
});
```

***Edit:***
After this, `document.write(x + " Results");` still won't work, because it executes before the iframe has been loaded. You need to do a check asynchronously.

Here is ***[the live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dybuZ/)***.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = 0;
    $('iframe').load(function() {
        x++;        
    });
    var time_id = setInterval(function() {
      $('#count').text(x);
      if (x === $('iframe').length) {
        clearInterval(time_id);
      }
    }, 200);
});​
```

The html:

```
<iframe  src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
<iframe  src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
<iframe  src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
<iframe  src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
<hr>
Loaded iframe count: <span id="count">0<span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has "function scope" - variables exist only within the function they were created in. So it is possible to have several different variables named `x`, if and only if they are in different functions (which is the case here).

Variables are created with the `var` keyword and accessed without a keyword. So, `var x = 10;` creates a variable named `x`, and `x = 10;` modifies an existing variable named `x`.

In your code every function calls `var x = 10;`. Since the previously defined `x` was defined in an outer function, that line is valid and created a new variable named `x`, scoped to the function it is being called in. If you were to omit the `var` statement, the interpreter would first look at the current function's namespace and not find `x`. Then it would move up to the global scope and find the `x` that you already declared, and use that.

In short, omit the word `var` in every line except line 1:

```
var x = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#iframe-2').load(function () {
        x = x + 1;
    });
    $('#iframe-3').load(function () {
        x = x + 1;
    });
    $('#iframe-4').load(function () {
        x = x + 1;
    });
    $('#iframe-5').load(function () {
        x = x + 1;
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you! I appreciate a lot the help...however I am still getting the same result :(

Comment: @user791187 Can you post the complete webpage you're using to test this?

Answer (score 0):

Another alter solution for above query using jQuery is here...

HTML:

```
<div id="top"></div>
<iframe  src="http://jquery.com/"></iframe>
<iframe  src="http://jquery.com/"></iframe>
<iframe  src="http://jquery.com/"></iframe>
<iframe  src="http://jquery.com/"></iframe>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

JQuery:

```
var x = 0;
$(function() {
    $('iframe:eq(0)').load(function() {
        x = x + 1;
        result(x);
    });
    $('iframe:eq(1)').load(function() {
        x = x + 1;
        result(x);
    });
    $('iframe:eq(2)').load(function() {
        x = x + 1;
        result(x);
    });
    $('iframe:eq(3)').load(function() {
        x = x + 1;
        result(x);
    });

});

function result(x) {
    if (x == null || typeof(x) == "undefined") x = 0;
    $("#top").html("<div>Loaded iframe count: " + x + "</div><hr/>");
    $("#bottom").html("<hr/><div>Loaded iframe count: " + x + "</div>");
}
```

Try on codebins too http://codebins.com/codes/home/4ldqpbk