# How to increment jQuery variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, increment, var

I'm trying to browse through a picture gallery with jquery, so I have a button which is supposed to increment a variable by 1 and then use that to load the next picture.

Using the top answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338499/increment-variable-using-jquery) SO question, I thought this would be the solution:

```
<div id="pic"></div>
<div id="browse-right">NEXT</div>

<%= image_tag("/1.JPG", id:"1") %>
<%= image_tag("/2.JPG", id:"2") %>
<%= image_tag("/3.JPG", id:"3") %>

$("#1").click(function() {
  var x = 1;
  $("#pic").html('<img src="/' + x + '.JPG" />');
});
$("#2").click(function() {
  var x = 2;
  $("#pic").html('<img src="/' + x + '.JPG" />');
});
$("#3").click(function() {
  var x = 3;
  $("#pic").html('<img src="/' + x + '.JPG" />');
});
//...
$("#browse-right").click(function() {
  x = x + 1;
  $("#pic").html('<img src="/' + x + '.JPG" />');
});
```

But it just reloads the same picture, which means `var x` doesn't change. Anyone know the proper syntax?

**UPDATE: Okay, I think I've figured out the problem. `x` is set when a picture is clicked on, and apparently it isn't persisting after the function is complete. I didn't include that part in the original code because I thought it would make the whole thing more complicated to read.....lesson learned. How can I get `x` to persist after the function it is set in?**

Comment: Should there be a semicolon on the third line?

Comment: Youve edited your code a bunch. Please update what the problem is when your done. If you step through the javascript and watch variable x, does it not increase? Does it get stuck at 1 or 2?

Comment: Can you also provide the context (aka rest of the code) around this individual piece of code?

Comment: @DanielHoffmann-Mitscherling It gets stuck at 1.

Comment: what is #pic element?

Comment: @EJTH It's just the wrapper that the next picture is supposed to appear into.

Comment: Is #browse-right an `<a>`?

Comment: @EJTH No, it's a standard div.

Comment: That issue for sure does not happen at all. Please provide more code for us to verify the issue.

Comment: _"var x doesn't change"_ Cannot reproduce http://jsfiddle.net/t6qttr8y/

Comment: fyi, you can shorten `x = x + 1` to just `x++;` Also, i'd tighten the scope of this and remove the outside `x`. I would write it as `$("#browse-right").click(function(e) {!this['i']?this.i=1:this.i++;$("#pic").html('<img src="/' + this.i + '.JPG" />');});`

Comment: @guest271314 My variable isn't persisting outside of the function it is set in. I added more code, which hopefully is more helpful.

Comment: @mc10 My variable isn't persisting outside of the function it is set in. I added more code, which hopefully is more helpful.

Comment: @JoeMorano Try defining `x` outside of and before attaching `click` handlers, see post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I get x to persist after the function it is set in?

Try defining `x` outside of and before `click` handler

```js
var x = 1;
$("body").on("click", function() {
  x = x + 1;
  $(this).html(x)
})
```

```css
body {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
click
```

Comment: Wait a second, now x is always 1. How can I set it with a click?

Comment: _"now x is always 1"_ Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to create a jsfiddle to demonstrate that. But if I set `x = 5`, by say clicking on picture `#5`, and then click on `#browse-right`, `x` is set to 2, not 6.

Comment: @JoeMorano _"not sure how to create a jsfiddle to demonstrate that"_ Include `html` at upper-left textarea , `js` at lower-left textarea , `css` at upper-right textarea ; select jQuery at "Framesworks & Extensions" , click "Run"

Comment: @JoeMorano Try removing `var` declaration within `click` handler , which declares new _local_ variable `x` within handler ; does not refer to global variable `x` . See http://jsfiddle.net/eqfrrfsf/2/ , http://jsfiddle.net/r5do7808/

Comment: @JoeMorano You should really read up on [***scope***](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/)

Comment: @guest271314 There we go!!! Thank you, I was starting to tear my hair out over this one.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok. and here's a working version https://jsfiddle.net/a50nz178/1/

A couple of things you could check:

- check that the image is actually there `/1.JPG`as well
- check that images are not all named as `jpg` all lower case?

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, looking at your *previous* <sub>You've updated. Turns out I was right. Your `x` was out of scope.</sub> correct code, I'd bet your problem is *scope*. [<sub>Scope Tutorial</sub>](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/)

I'm willing to bet, somewhere else in your code your using something like `for(x in ; ...` Which is reassigning `x`. If that's not the case, I'd still bet on either scope, or the image is `src` isn't correct. You should use your developer console to check if a bad image source is being pulled. Your using `/` at the begining of your `img src` which will go back to `base path`. If you images are in an images folder you need to include the proper directory path.

You could easily shorten the scope of this by attaching your increment variable to your element object like so:

```js
$("#browse-right").click(function(e) {
    //  the following is a simple inline `if` statement
    //  what it says is (this is your element)
    //  if this.i does not exist, create it equal to one, 
    //  else count it up once
    !this['i'] ? this.i=1: this.i++;
    $("#pic").html('<img src="/' + this.i + '.JPG" />');
    //  the following simply shows what `i` currently is
    $('h3').text(this.i);
});
```

```css
p { cursor: pointer; background: #aabb00; padding: 1em .5em; text-align: center; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="browse-right">Browse Right</p>
<h3></h3>
<div id="pic">
  IMG HERE
</div>
```